# How many options are there for creating a number from the digits 123454321?

Tags: combinatorics

I thought the answer was `9!` but it's obviously isn't.
I thought you have 9 options at first, then 8, then 7, etc.

Anyone can shed some light on the case?

Comment: Look this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

Comment: You don't have $9$ options first, you have $5$. But that way of thinking about it becomes messy.

Comment: Yes, I understand why 5 (because you have 4 numbers that have dupplicates), but what's after the 5 at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{9!}{2!×2!×2!×2!}=\frac{9!}{2^4}=22680$$

Comment: Frankly, I am tempted to downvote this (I won't, don't worry): While technically correct, it doesn't help both OP nor anyone else stumbling upon this to _understand_ the solution let alone use it for similar problems

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It helped the OP, otherwise the OP probably wouldn't have accepted it.

Comment: @wythagoras it did, which indicates OP is lazy ;-) the answer is perfectly valid, what I meant is that ideally an answer helps the entire community and not just an individual

Answer (score 10):

To understand why the answer provided by Wyctus works, we label the ones as (1,1) and (1,2).

Now consider (1,1)23454(1,2)32 and (1,2)23454(1,1)32. This both gives 123454132. So we have to divide by the way to arrange two different ones, namely 2!. This is similiar for the twos, threes, and fours, so we divide by $2! \times 2! \times 2! \times 2!=16$.

Comment: you should add this to Wyctus anwser

Comment: @mattecapu This answer adds a substantial amount of information—enough to stand on its own.

Comment: @mattecapu That would change that "answer"'s entire being. If OP wants to accept an unexplaining answer, they should be able to do so

Answer (score 3):

You can choose where to place the 4's in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways, 
then  the 3's in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways,

and then the 2's in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, and finally the 1's in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways;

so there are $\displaystyle\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}=22,680$ such numbers.